# What do "Player Score" & "Military Strength" mean under Domination Victory?

Tags: civilization-6

Under Domination Victory it shows "Player Score" and "Military Strength".

How are these calculated? I assume "Military Strength" is some kind of total of all your military units & districts. I can't even guess what "Player Score" means.

Obviously, neither is in Civipedia.

Comment: You can see a breakdown of the player score somewhere, probably in the victory progress or even in the screen you are talking about. Basically it gives points for territory size, cities, wonders, great people, techs and policies, etc. Just a way to tell how well you are faring compared to other civs.
Can't say how the Military Power is actually calculated though

Comment: Military power is calculated through the number of units and their tech level. So you could have 2 mustketmen with similar military power to 10 warriors. (May not be that precise but that's the gist). Districts don't get calculated because if you have 0 military units your military strength will be at 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The player score is a metric to compare how well civilizations are doing. According to this [civfanatics forum post](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/score-victory-empire-points.609841/), player score is calculated by

> +2 for each tech and civic
>   +5 For each wonder
>   +3 for each great person (awarded on recieving GP)
>   +4 for a pantheon and +8 for a religion (not much value for using religion)
>
> Empire seems to consists of
>   +5 per city
>   +1 per population
>   +3 per district

---

Military strength is a metric for comparing how strong a civilizations military is. According to this [civfantics forum post](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/military-strength.619448/#post-14801347), it's calculated by the sum of the strengths of the units you have.